# Solutions to a Linear Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $S$ and $T$ be vector spaces and $L : S\longrightarrow T$ be a linear map. Say $v_1$ and $v_2$ are distinct solutions of the equation $Lx = y_1$ while $w$ is a solution of $Lx = y_2$.
In terms of $v_1$,$v_2$, and $w$,

Please help some solution of $Lx = 2y_1 − 7y_2$ ?
Please find another solution (other than $w$) of $Lx = y_2$.

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: what means *by definition* that $v$ is a solution of $Lx=y$? If $y_1=L(\cdots)$ and $y_2=L(\cdots)$ (with $L$ *linear*), what is $2y_1−7y_2$?

EDIT:

Hypothesis:
$$Lv_1=y_1,\qquad Lv_2=y_1,\qquad Lw=y_2.$$
Then,
$$2y_1−7y_2=2Lv_1-7Lw=\cdots$$

Comment: It's a linear combination of bases which are solutions?? I have no idea here.

Comment: @Jimmy, see mi edit.